# UITextview - UIKeyboard dismiss

Tags: ios, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have to dismiss the `UIKeyboard` while entering the "done" button when I am in `UITextView`.

Note: I tried it with `UITextView`. It works fine and I want to implement the same concept in UITextview.  I have tried the

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

methods, but that has issues.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't get you. you have already tried with UITextView and now you want to implement with UITextView?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift:**

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        theTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UITextView does not have option to have done button, because it need to have return button. You can catch press on return button but its not really recommended. Recommended way to dismiss keyboard while editing UITextView is tap gesture recognizer on main view or other elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Use following code, might be useful for you :)**

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
{

        if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) 
        {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ivan Alek is right , `UITextView` needs the return button in order to move the cursor on the next line. You can add a view over the keyboard and dismiss the keyboard from a button. Like this:

```
UIToolbar       *toolbar    = [[[UIToolbar       alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 30)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *item2      = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(closeKeyboard)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *item1      = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1 , item2, nil]];
[textView setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
```

And then in the `closeKeyboard` method you can resign the first responder.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

add Done button on accessorary view of keyboard and implement done method with

```
  [textView resignFirstResponder];
```

and don't forget to set delegate for textView.